Buck converter with high amperage?
I currently have two separate circuits, but I would like to combine them using a single power supply. Normally I would consider something like a buck converter, but I have a very high amperage pulled by the load on the 22.2V circuit, and I wasn't sure what sort of changes would need to be made to protect the lower circuit. What sort of circuit could I consider here to achieve something like the bottom setup?
EDIT:
The ESC is ~22-24V though it can drop a bit lower, and the sensor is ~11-12.5V


Your supply only has to deliver 3A, no matter the load on the input (22.2V).  There are numerous ICs, with or without an external pass transistor, which can accomplish this.
One issue you probably want to look at is how hard your 150A load pulls the battery voltage, and how it changes.  You want a supply with good input rejection to best regulate the 12V if there's excessive noise on the input.
If the load is intermittent inductive, you should also measure it to find the maximum spikes the supply will have to handle.

A current-mode buck converter should work fine here.

The ESC powers drone motors and this load can pull anywhere from 0 to 150A very quickly (more like 100A spikes, but sometimes can be this high). The battery voltage starts around 24V, and quickly falls to around a 22V nominal voltage. The sensor pulls 8W continuously with occasional 3A spikes
